# Outlook on Terminalserver loses connection. Event ID 26

Tags: exchange, outlook, terminal-server, terminal, eventviewer

**Problem Symptoms:** 
Users experience daily disconnects and reconnects in Outlook running on a Terminal Server and have to log in again. They can not log in instantly but have to wait for approx. 1 minute.

**What i found out in the Event log:**
I realized that there are several log entrys with the ID 26 coming from outlook on the Terminal Server (See below in the Screenshot link):

[image: Event Viewer Screenshot]

I tryed a continous ping from the Terminal Server towards the Exchange Server and the connection seemed stable.

The Antivirus does its scans late at night (Around 23:00) and should not interfere.

I've checked numerous Forums and cant find the answer to why those disconnects happen.

**Additional Info:**

- Terminal Server: windows Server 2008 R2 with sp1
- Exchange Server: Windows Server 2016 Std
- AD Server: Windows Server 2016 Std
- All the Servers were last updated on 30.05.2018.

The issue is visible in the Terminal Server log since 03.05.2018 which means that the Problem started before we updated the Server.

Comment: May be due to incompatible Maximum Transmission Unit (MTU) between Terminal server and Exchange server. Refer to : [Incorrect MTU size causes connectivity issues with Windows Server 2012 and Windows Server 2012 R2](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askpfeplat/2014/12/01/psa-incorrect-mtu-size-causes-connectivity-issues-with-windows-server-2012-and-windows-server-2012-r2/)